# React Show a List Of Buttons on Button click

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick

I'm starting with React and i'm making a simple app to practice, in this app i got the App.js that have this code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core/';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import BotonInicial from './components/botonInicial'
import NumeroJugadores from './components/numeroJugadores'


function App() {

return (
  <Box color="text.primary" clone>
    <Container maxWidth="sm" style={{ textAlign: "center" }} >

      <Typography variant="h2" component="h2" style={{ color: "grey", verticalAlign: 
        "middle", padding: "10px" }}>
        Five Crowns Counter
      </Typography>

      <BotonInicial label={"Empieza el Juego!!"} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <NumeroJugadores visible="true"/>

    </Container>
  </Box>
);


 }

 export default App;
```

And in two different files got the "BotonInicial" And the "NumeroJugadores" Components.

**botonInicial.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core/';

function BotonInicial(params) {
      console.log(params)
      return (
      <Button 
        variant="contained" 
        color="secondary" 
        style= {{padding: "20px"}} 
        onClick={Change the state on the NumeroJugadores Component}
      >
      {params.label}
      </Button>
      );
  }
  
  export default BotonInicial;
```

**numeroJugadores.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {ButtonGroup , Button} from '@material-ui/core/';


function NumeroJugadores(params) {
    if(params.visilble){
    return (
      <ButtonGroup variant="contained" color="primary" aria-label="contained primary button group" >
        <Button>1 P</Button>
        <Button>2 P</Button>
        <Button>3 P</Button>
        <Button>4 P</Button>
        <Button>5 P</Button>
        <Button>6 P</Button>
        <Button>7 P</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
    );
    }else {return null;}
  
}
  
  export default NumeroJugadores;
```

I'm trying this functionality: When the user clicks the button, the "NumeroJugadores" should appear changing the prop of "visible" = true. I've tried with states, and the state Hook, but no success. What approach should i have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react hooks to help conditionally show/hide an element.

In your App.js (notice that I removed the visible="true" in `NumeroJugadores`, I added a `handler` param in BotonInicial, and added a conditional using `visible`)

The conditional with `visible` basically means that, if `visible` is true, then render `NumeroJugadores`

```
function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const showButtons = () => setVisible(true);

  return (
    <Box color="text.primary" clone>
      <Container maxWidth="sm" style={{ textAlign: "center" }} >

        <Typography variant="h2" component="h2" style={{ color: "grey", verticalAlign: 
          "middle", padding: "10px" }}>
          Five Crowns Counter
        </Typography>

        <BotonInicial label={"Empieza el Juego!!"} handler={showButtons} />
        <br />
        <br />
        {!!visible && <NumeroJugadores />}

      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

For your `BotonInicial`, pass the `handler` to `onClick`

```
function BotonInicial(params) {
      console.log(params)
      return (
      <Button 
        variant="contained" 
        color="secondary" 
        style= {{padding: "20px"}} 
        onClick={params.handler}
      >
      {params.label}
      </Button>
      );
  }
```

And then you can now clean up NumeroJugadores,

```
function NumeroJugadores() {
    return (
      <ButtonGroup variant="contained" color="primary" aria-label="contained primary button group" >
        <Button>1 P</Button>
        <Button>2 P</Button>
        <Button>3 P</Button>
        <Button>4 P</Button>
        <Button>5 P</Button>
        <Button>6 P</Button>
        <Button>7 P</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
    );
}
```